# How to make a valid REST call with authentication in Java

Tags: java, rest, authentication, https

I am trying to write a Java class file that authenticates to a system using a HTTP Rest call )post in this case).

I have tried the following code, but I get an error stating:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"The request could not be understood","developerMessage":"The request body did not contain valid JSON"}]}
```

here is my code:

```
public class simplePost {

    private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://xxxxxx/xxxxx/token");

        CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials("username", "password"));

        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "xxxxxxxxxx")); 
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "xxxxxx"));

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line;
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error. When I put in the URI and login information in Postman or AdvanceRestClient, I get the proper response.

Comment: The error message says  "The request body did not contain valid JSON". Check the post body (json) - Particularly -  post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

Comment: UrlEncodedForm is not JSON. And why would the credentials go into both POST body and Auth header?

Comment: how do I make the UrlEncodedForm json??